# One workbook having strange access to another workbook's module

Tags: excel, vba

Very peculiar occurrence. I have the code below in one workbook. Then in a separate workbook, I was debugging code when I noticed that the below code is being called?!?! The code resides in the `thisworkbook` module of the first book so should be contained only in that book. How is the second book even "seeing" it???

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.Name = "Checks" Then

    If Abs(Sh.Range("R25").Value) > 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 10, 10)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Edit: code in second book residing in a module:

```
Sub UpdateWorkbook()

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a formula that is referencing a cell in the other workbook?  Changing a "referenced" value could be triggering the calculation in the workbook that has the macro?  (If so you might want to change `ActiveSheet.Tab.Color` to `Sh.Tab.Color` and `ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex ` to `Sh.Tab.ColorIndex `?

Comment: @Demetri lol I am so bad. That's what `activesheet` mean doesn't it XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate one Excel workbook, I believe it recalculates all open workbooks - since your module runs on recalculation, it isn't being opened 'from' the active workbook, because the workbook with the code in it actually recalculates on its own, whenever any workbook recalculates.

The solution would be to either keep the workbook closed when not in use, or create a generic If statement loop, checking whether the active workbook was the one you wanted the code to run in.

Comment: This appears to be true. And because my code has `activesheet` it triggers the sub... I should've noticed this XD

Comment: An additional point which I didn't mention though @Demitri did in his comment - this could happen not just when the entire workbook recalculates, but also when a single cell referenced in the other workbook changes - so if there are cells in common, this could happen more frequently.

Comment: Hmmm this is kind of inefficient. I add `If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then` to the first book and while it does skip the code, that calc event is still being triggered unnecessarily :/ So the only sure way is close the book entirely?

Comment: @findwindow Or don't use the global 'On Recalculate' trigger for that module. I don't know what is meant to change that the code needs to run on recalculate, but if you can find a more specific trigger, then it won't apply whenever any open workbook Calculates.

Comment: I suppose you could even make that workbook calculate manually only, although that would likely create problems in the future if it is also being used as a 'normal' workbook, where a user would expect automatic recalculation.

Comment: @findwindow I actually like your solution of using the `If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then`.  I can't imagine that it adds any significant level of time to process does it?

Comment: @Demetri and Grade, thank you both. It appears the event's scope is app wide not book wide which is kinda dumb but that's m$ft XD While processing time is not even noticeable, it's just dumb in principal. BUT, now every time I debug, I have to step through that if statement XD

Comment: No shouldn't take much time to process at all - and your full workbook recalculations probably happen very infrequently anyway, so no point in even optimizing, in my opinion. I suppose you could hardcode the value of the Thisworkbook.Name, to save it pulling that value each time, but again, probably not worth it to even do that. It's a trivial calculation for the code to perform as-is.

Comment: @findwindow One final note - if you are running through code using f8, then when the code jumps over to your other workbook, it may become 'active' by default, meaning that while debugging the IF statement could still run unintentionally. May need to account for that in another method.

Comment: lol I am about to just delete that sub. Was supposed to make life easier but clearly the opposite XD Edit: now I know that event is useless.